# handler and service: multiple UI updates

Tags: android, multithreading, android-service, android-handler

I need to start service in background, which can show custom Toast each interval of time, then I make service and in its thread I have made infinite while loop with sleep thread to make the interval.

My problem that, in each time I have to show the super Toast I need to call the handler, which is okay, but the major problem that the Toast is shown only for one time! although there is infinite while loop condition!

**the following is the Service : onStartCommand**

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Log.i(TAG, "Service onStartCommand");

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Looper.prepare();
            mHandler = new Handler() {
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    //Looper.myLooper().quit();
                    Random r = new Random();
                    int i1 = r.nextInt(items.size() - 0) + 0;
                    superToast.setBackground(SuperToast.Background.GREEN);
                    superToast.setAnimations(SuperToast.Animations.FLYIN);
                    superToast.setText(items.get(i1));
                    superToast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT, 0, 0);
                    superToast.show();
                    Log.i("Handeler", "Handeler");
                }
            };

            while (isRunning) {
                Random r2 = new Random();
                time = r2.nextInt(Max - Min) + Min;
                mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(time);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (isRunning) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Service running");
                }
                Looper.loop();
            }
        }
    }).start();

    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: try giving some constant time like 5 secs first instead of random. May be your random number is generating very small number. Also set the duration of toast to short and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating Runnable and posting Runnable in Handler using `mHandler.post(Runnable);` inside while loop

Comment: could you give me an example?

Comment: inside the Runnable Thread, I have entered this 
  mHandler.post(this);
                    Looper.loop();

Comment: but I got the same problem! it just runs once time

Answer (score 0):

You don't understand how the `Looper` works.

Even though you have written an infinite loop in your `run()` method, you aren't actually making more than 1 pass through your `while` loop. The reason is that the call to `Looper.loop()` never returns.

In order to do what you want, you need to have 2 `Thread`s. The first `Thread` should contain your infinite `while` loop, sending a message and sleeping inside the `while` loop.

The other `Thread` should call `Looper.prepare()`, create the `Handler` and then call `Looper.loop()`.

The call to `Looper.loop()` blocks the `Thread` waiting for something to be queued to the `Looper`'s message queue. When something is put in the message queue (by the first `Thread`), the `Looper` dequeues the message and calls `onHandleMessage()` on the `Handler`, then it goes back and blocks waiting for something to be queued to the message queue.